# You keep your trap shut and I'll keep your trap open

Tags: slang, phrase-meaning

In this [commercial](https://youtu.be/q7LwRFhfRQc?t=3m6s) the lawyer says to a potential client:

> You keep your trap shut and I'll keep your trap open

What does it mean?

Comment: *Trap* is slang for *mouth*, so the first part of the sentence is easy to understand. From the context, I imagine that the second part of the sentence means "I'll do the talking for you."

Comment: It means keep your mouth shut and i'll get you off -- I'll get you out of the mess you created and keep you out of jail.

Comment: I would venture to suggest that any lawyer (solicitor or barrister) in the UK who had the chutzpah to run this kind of ad would soon find himself hauled before the the Law Society or Bar Council to face disciplinary action for bringing the profession into disrepute. Is this for real or might it have been screened on 1st April? Shakespeare penned the line, "The first thing we do, let's kill all the lawyers" in Henry Vl, Part ll. Nuff said. I think I'd better keep my trap shut from now on lest any ambulance chaser or shyster out there gets writ happy!

Comment: Regarding *Is this for real?*: Hard to tell. According to this article http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/jurisprudence/2014/03/daniel_muessig_video_the_man_behind_the_best_or_worst_lawyer_commercial.html he is a real lawyer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a saying among drug dealers.

*Keep your trap shut*:

Here, *trap* means mouth. So it means to keep your mouth closed no matter what the police, or anybody for that matter, say.

*Keep your trap open*:

A trap is a place (usually an abandoned house) where drug dealers make money and I'm talking money not just a few dollars I mean thousands and thousands of dollars 24x7. And so it means "I'll keep your business running".

References: Urban Dictionary [1](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=trap%20house) and [2](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Trap)

Comment: Are you saying that the whole expression (both halves) is familiar among drug dealiers?

Comment: He's saying that a trap is a drug selling "establishment". If that is so, he's right.

Answer (score 9):

"Keep your trap shut" is a colloquial expression meaning "don't talk".  In this case the "trap" in question is the client's mouth.  This is likely an invocation of lawyers' frequent advice for their clients never to speak to law enforcement officers without a lawyer present, since such loose talk is admissible in any subsequent court case and is almost exclusively detrimental to the defense.

"I'll keep your trap open" is not a common saying, but is rather a play on the other saying.  It is likely supposed to mean that the lawyer will keep his client out of prison.  In this case "trap" means prison.

Putting it all together, then, the lawyer is advising his potential clients not to speak to police until hiring him, thus maximizing his ability to prevent a lengthy jail sentence.

Comment: The trap he's offering to keep open is possibly whatever hole the potential client's in danger of getting himself into. This might not just be jail but also civil action.